# What is $T>0$ large enough such that $\mu\left(B\right)<\varepsilon$?

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $\left(M,\sigma,\mu\right)$ where $\sigma$ is a Borell $\sigma$-algebra
and $\mu$ is a probability $f$-invariant. Let $x\in M$, $E\subset M$ measurable
and $f:M\rightarrow M$ a measurable transformation, given $x\in M$
we define

$\tau_{n}\left(E,x\right)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\mathcal{X}_{E}\left(f^{j}\left(x\right)\right)$

where $\mathcal{X}_{E}$ is characteristic function, also we define

$\overline{\tau}\left(E,x\right)=\limsup_{n}\tau_{n}\left(E,x\right)$

Given $\varepsilon>0$ we define the function

\begin{eqnarray*}
t_{\varepsilon}:M & \rightarrow & \mathbb{Z}\\
x & \rightarrow & t_{\varepsilon}\left(x\right)=\min\left\{ n\geq0\::\,\tau_{n}\left(E,x\right)\geq\overline{\tau}\left(E,x\right)-\varepsilon\right\} .
\end{eqnarray*}
Show that there is $T>0$ large enough such that the set

$B=\left\{ x\in M\,:\, t_{\varepsilon}\left(x\right)>T\right\} $

has measure $\mu\left(B\right)<\varepsilon$.

**Remark:** This is a problem that I found on the proof of one version of the Poincaré recurrence theorem, this version is:

> *Let* $\left(M,\sigma,\mu\right)$ *where* $\sigma$ *is a Borell* $\sigma$-*algebra*
>   *and* $\mu$ *is a probability* $f$-*invariant whit* $f:M\rightarrow M$ *a measurable transformation. Given* $E\subset M$ *measurable, then the limit*
>
> $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\mathcal{X}_{E}\left(f^{j}\left(x\right)\right)=\tau\left(E,x\right)$
>
> *exists. Furthermore,*
>
> $\int\tau\left(E,x\right)d\mu=\mu\left(E\right)$

In the proof of this theorem is used the fact:

> $\int\overline{\tau}\left(E,x\right)d\mu\leq\mu\left(E\right)\leq\int\underline{\tau}\left(E,x\right)d\mu$

The idea of the proof of this fact is as follows:

Given $\varepsilon>0$ and $E\in M$ measurable we define the functión
\begin{eqnarray*}
t_{\varepsilon}:M & \rightarrow & \mathbb{Z}\\
x & \rightarrow & t_{\varepsilon}\left(x\right)=\min\left\{ n\geq0\::\,\tau_{n}\left(E,x\right)\geq\overline{\tau}\left(E,x\right)-\varepsilon\right\} .
\end{eqnarray*}

[image]

Therefore, we have two cases:

1. $t_{\varepsilon}$ **is bounded**, i.e, there is $T>0$ such that $t_{\varepsilon}\left(x\right)<T$ for all $x\in M$. In this case, given $x\in M$ we define the points $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{s},x_{s+1}$  in $M$ and the numbers  $t_{1},t_{2},\ldots,t_{s},t_{s+1}$ as follows:

   - **i)**  $x_{0}=x$
   - **ii)**  If $x_{i}$ was defined, we define $t_{i}=t_{\varepsilon}\left(x_{i}\right)$  and $x_{i+1}=f^{t_{i}}\left(x_{i}\right)$
   - **iii)** We finalized when we find $x_{s+1}$ such that $t_{1}+t_{2}+\ldots+t_{s}+t_{s+1}\geq n-1$

   We have constructed the following sequence
   [image]

   The number of visits of the point $x_i$ to the set $E$ from iteration $0$ to iteration $t_{i}-1$ is $t_{i}\tau\left(E,x_{i}\right)$. Furthermore, by construction it follows

   $t_{i}\tau_{t_{i}}\left(E,x_{i}\right)\geq t_{i}\left(\overline{\tau}\left(E,x_{i}\right)-\varepsilon\right)$ for each $i=1,2,\cdots,s$.

   Moreover, we know that $x_{i}=f^{t_{0}+t_{1}+\cdots+t_{i-1}}\left(x_{i-1}\right)$ and $\overline{\tau}\left(E,*\right)$  is $f$-invariant (is not dificult the proof), then

   $\overline{\tau}\left(E,x\right)=\overline{\tau}\left(E,x_{0}\right)=\overline{\tau}\left(E,x_{1}\right)=\cdots=\overline{\tau}\left(E,x_{s}\right)=\overline{\tau}\left(E,x_{s+1}\right).$

   Therefore,

   $t_{i}\tau_{t_{i}}\left(E,x_{i}\right)\geq t_{i}\left(\overline{\tau}\left(E,x\right)-\varepsilon\right)$ for each $i=1,2,\cdots,s$

   thus, as

   $t_{0}+t_{1}+\cdots+t_{s}\geq t_{0}+t_{1}+\cdots+t_{s}+t_{s+1}+T\geq n-1-T$

   and the number of visits of the point $x$ to the set $E$ under iteration of $f$ from iteration $0$ to iteration $n-1$ is $n\tau_{n}\left(E,x\right)$, then

   \begin{eqnarray*}
   n\tau_{n}\left(E,x\right) & = & \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mathcal{X}_{E}\left(f^{j}\left(x\right)\right)\geq\sum_{i=0}^{s}t_{i}\tau_{t_{i}}\left(E,x_{i}\right)\\
    & \geq & \left(\sum_{i=0}^{s}t_{i}\right)\left(\overline{\tau}\left(E,x\right)-\varepsilon\right)\geq\left(n-1-T\right)\left(\overline{\tau}\left(E,x\right)-\varepsilon\right)
   \end{eqnarray*}
   Integrating with respect to $x$ we obtain

   \begin{eqnarray*}
   n\mu\left(E\right) & = & \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mu\left(E\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\int\mathcal{X}_{E}\left(f^{j}\left(x\right)\right)d\mu\\
    & = & \int\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mathcal{X}_{E}\left(f^{j}\left(x\right)\right)d\mu\geq\left(n-1-T\right)\int\left(\overline{\tau}\left(E,x\right)-\varepsilon\right)d\mu
   \end{eqnarray*}
   Therefore

   $\mu\left(E\right)\geq\left(1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{T}{n}\right)\int\overline{\tau}\left(E,x\right)d\mu+\left(1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{T}{n}\right)\varepsilon$

   Considering the limit when $n\rightarrow\infty$ we obtain

   $\mu\left(E\right)\geq\int\overline{\tau}\left(E,x\right)d\mu+\varepsilon$

   Given that $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, then

   $\mu\left(E\right)\geq\int\overline{\tau}\left(E,x\right)d\mu$.

   The other inequality

   $\mu\left(E\right)\leq\int\underline{\tau}\left(E,x\right)d\mu$

   is obtained following a similar path, changing $t_{\varepsilon}$ by the function  $\hat{t}_{\varepsilon}$ given by

   \begin{eqnarray*}
   \hat{t}_{\varepsilon}:M & \rightarrow & \mathbb{Z}\\
   x & \rightarrow & \hat{t}_{\varepsilon}\left(x\right)=\min\left\{ n\geq0\::\,\tau_{n}\left(E,x\right)\leq\underline{\tau}\left(E,x\right)+\varepsilon\right\} .
   \end{eqnarray*}

The other case is:

2. $t_{\varepsilon}$ **is unbounded**.  In this case ***we choose*** $T$ *large enough such that the set* 
   $B=\left\{ y\in M\::\: t_{\epsilon}\left(y\right)>T\right\} $ 
   *has very small measure, ie* $\mu \left(B\right)<\varepsilon$.
   Similarly to case **1**, we define the points $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{s},x_{s+1}$  in $M$ and the numbers  $t_{1},t_{2},\ldots,t_{s},t_{s+1}$ as follows:

   - **i)**  $x_{0}=x$
   - **ii)** If $x_{i}$ was defined, we consider two situations:

     - a) If $x_{i}\notin B$, We define as in case 1 $t_{i}=t_{\varepsilon}\left(x_{i}\right)$  and $x_{i+1}=f^{t_{i}}\left(x_{i}\right)$
     - b) If $x_{i}\in B$, We define $t_{i}=1$  and $x_{i+1}=f^{t_{i}}\left(x_{i}\right)$.
   - **iii)** We finalized when we find $x_{s+1}$ such that $t_{1}+t_{2}+\ldots+t_{s}+t_{s+1}\geq n-1$

   Similarly to Case 1 we show that for all $x_{i}$

   $\sum_{j=0}^{t_{i}-1}\mathcal{X}_{E}\left(f^{j}\left(x_{i}\right)\right)\geq t_{i}\left(\overline{\tau}\left(E,x\right)-\varepsilon\right)-\sum_{j=0}^{t_{i}-1}\mathcal{X}_{B}\left(f^{j}\left(x_{j}\right)\right)$

   Therefore

   $n\tau_{n}\left(E,x\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mathcal{X}_{E}\left(f^{j}\left(x\right)\right)\geq\left(n-1-T\right)\left(\overline{\tau}\left(E,x\right)-\varepsilon\right)-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\mathcal{X}_{B}\left(f^{j}\left(x_{j}\right)\right)$

   Integrating with respect to $x$ we obtain

   $n\mu\left(E\right)\geq\left(n-1-T\right)\int\overline{\tau}\left(E,x\right)d\mu-\left(n-1-T\right)\varepsilon-n\mu\left(B\right)$

   Dividing by $n$ and taking the limit when $n\rightarrow\infty$ we obtain

   \begin{eqnarray*}
   \mu\left(E\right) & \geq & \int\overline{\tau}\left(E,x\right)d\mu-\varepsilon-\mu\left(B\right)\\
    & \geq & \int\overline{\tau}\left(E,x\right)d\mu-2\varepsilon
   \end{eqnarray*}
   Hence

   $\mu\left(E\right)\geq\int\overline{\tau}\left(E,x\right)d\mu$.

   The other inequality

   $\mu\left(E\right)\leq\int\underline{\tau}\left(E,x\right)d\mu$

   is obtained following a similar path, changing $t_{\varepsilon}$ by the function  $\hat{t}_{\varepsilon}$.

   $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\square$

As seen, the problem is: ***choose*** $T$ ***large enough such that the set*** 
 $B=\left\{ y\in M\::\: t_{\epsilon}\left(y\right)>T\right\} $ 
 ***has very small measure, ie*** $\mu \left(B\right)<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Is there a question any where in this post?

Comment: @dustin I see one in the title.

Comment: The question still remains the same question as initially I proposed.
My intention is  show the situation in that I found this problem, in this case is  the Poincaré recurrence theorem, specifically, the problem is in one of the facts used to prove it, wrote the proof of this fact so you could see him importance of my question.